# How to make vscode show type info for exported function from another .js file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Showing type information in vscode for Typescript files is pretty simply via the `/// <reference path ...` comment. However, I have the case where I use exported functions from one js file in another. The exported functions have been annotated to contain type information. Here's an example (lib/index.js):

```
/**
 * Put the executing thread to sleep for the given amount of milliseconds.
 * @param {number} milliseconds
 */
exports.sleep = function (milliseconds) {
    var end = new Date().getTime() + milliseconds;
    while (new Date().getTime() < end) { }
}
```

In my main.js file I do:

```
var lib = require("lib");
lib.sleep(500);
```

Unfortunately, vscode does not provide the call signature of that `sleep` function nor can I use cmd/ctrl+click to navigate to it.

I also created a typings file and referenced that in main.js, which works almost like I want, except that it doesn't take me to the original source, but instead to the typings file when I cmd/ctrl+click on the function name.

Is it possible and how to let vscode recognize exports in other JS files and provide call information and code navigation for them?

Comment: try to change require path to `./lib`

Comment: would rather use `Date.now()` then `getTime`... but what i would change the most is to make it callback or promise based using setTimeout, Its never a good idea to block the thread

Comment: @MaxSinev damn, you nailed it. That simple change solved the issue. Please provide an answer which I can accept.

Comment: @Endless yes, I know, this is for a very special situation and identified as the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `require` path to `./lib`

```
var lib = require("./lib");
lib.sleep(500);
```